# How to implicitly get opengl 4.2 from Mesa3D

Tags: windows, opengl, mesa

I need opengl 4.2 for my app to run on server(windows). So I found Mesa3D software implementation of opengl will solve my purpose. I built Mesa3D 19.0.0 for windows. But when use opengl32.dll and lib given by Mesa , default version is coming as 3.1 . I tried checking their documentation, I didn't understand how to get Opengl 4.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You'll have to pour a bunch of time/effort/money into the Mesa project.</strike>

Currently their software renderers (softpipe/llvmpipe/swr) [only support up to OpenGL 3.3 Core](https://mesamatrix.net/#Version_OpenGL3.3-GLSL3.30).

Note that (currently) you'll have to request a Core context to get 3.3.  Compatibility contexts are limited to 3.0.

[As of Mesa 20.2 `llvmpipe` supports OpenGL 4.5](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/mesa-20.2.0/docs/features.txt#L213).

Comment: genpfault, Got you.Out of curiosity I'm asking, why are they mentioning like 4.x support is added in their release notes.?

Comment: @Raki: Those generally have only been applying to their various hardware drivers (Intel, AMD, etc.): "Mesa implements the OpenGL 4.5 API, but the version... *depends on the particular driver being used*."  The software renders hit 3.3 *years* ago and have just kinda...stayed there.